# Inequality + Percentage

Tags: inequality

"In a class, 40% of students want to study physics, while less than 33 1/3% of them want to study Chinese History.  If the number of students who want to study physics is 3 more than that of students who want to study Chinese History, at most how many students are there in the class?"

Don't know how to set up an inequality...please help.

Comment: Let $n$ be the number of students, $x$ the number of students who want to study physics and $y$ the number of students who want to study Chinese History. Can you translate your statements into mathematics using $n,\ x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $x$ is the number of students in the class, you know that $40\% x= \frac{2}{5}x$ want to study physics, **and** the number of students of Chinese History is $y< \frac{1}{3}x$, and if $z$ is the number of students that does not study physics nor Chines, you have the system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x= \frac{2}{5}x+y+z\\
\frac{2}{5}x-y=3\\
y< \frac{1}{3}x
\end{cases}
$$

can you solve?

---

Solution:

From the second equation:
$$
y=\frac{2}{5}x-3
$$
substituting in the first equation:
$$
x=5(z-3) \Rightarrow y=2z-9
$$
so the inequality becomes
$$
2z-9<\frac{5}{3} (z-3) \Rightarrow z<12 \Rightarrow x<45
$$

Comment: Solving I ve got x> 45 but that means minimum is 45 not 'at most'??

I think my math teacher has set the wrong questions,  besides, it is meaning less because how doesn't the number of students in the class is an unknown variable???

Comment: I've corrected my answer and the result is $x\le 45$.

Comment: Never seen such a system, may you please add the solution and method  to your answer so I have it in my tool box. @EmilioNovati

Comment: I've added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)

Answer (score 0):

The information given has two equalities and one inequality that is: $C < \frac{1}{3}n$ if C is number of students who want to Chinese History and n is total number of students in class.